# How do I extract rownames from a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, r-rownames

I have a matrix with rownames that are dates. I want to extract these row names into a variable, and then use `rownames()` to apply these dates to another matrix I have. Let's say the matrix is called 'data.matrix'.

Whenever I run:

```
data.matrix[,0]
```

I get a printout of all the dates. So I do this:

```
v <- data.matrix[,0]
```

When I return v I get a nice list of all the dates. But when I use:

```
rownames(other.matrix) <- v
```

And then I return:

```
head(other.matrix)
```

I don't get any new column names.

Also, when I try:

```
head(v)
```

I get `NULL`

But when I do:

```
v
```

I get a nice printout of all my dates.

So what gives? At first I thought that matrices and dates were incompatible but it seems as if they are.

Right now I'm using `merge()` in this way to add dates:

```
z <- merge(v, other.matrix)
```

But it feels like there's a better way to do this.

Comment: try: `rownames(other.matrix)  <- rownames(v)`

Answer (score 14):

The command

```
data.matrix[,0]
```

does return a matrix object without columns. Hence, you see its row names only.

To extract the rownames from an object, use the `rownames` function:

```
v <- rownames(data.matrix)
```