# Extract rownames from ts / mts object

Tags: r

Can anyone extract these dates?

```
class(Seatbelts)
#> [1] "mts" "ts"
Seatbelts
#>          DriversKilled drivers front rear   kms PetrolPrice VanKilled law
#> Jan 1969           107    1687   867  269  9059  0.10297181        12   0
#> Feb 1969            97    1508   825  265  7685  0.10236300         6   0
#> Mar 1969           102    1507   806  319  9963  0.10206249        12   0
...
Seatbelts[,0]
#>         
#> Jan 1969
#> Feb 1969
#> Mar 1969
...
rownames(Seatbelts)
#> NULL
row.names(Seatbelts)
#> NULL
row.names(as.matrix(Seatbelts))
#> NULL
```

I'm stumped. Have tried lots more besides above.

Related but unhelpful:

- [How do I extract rownames from a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301498/how-do-i-extract-rownames-from-a-matrix)
- [R: Converting "mts", "ts", "matrix" object to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490951/r-converting-mts-ts-matrix-object-to-data-frame)

Comment: The month/years are not row names. They are added by print.ts which derives it from the `tsp` attribute, try `attr(Seatbelts, "tsp")`, which is a 3 element vector stored in ts objects giving the start time, end time and frequency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time` can get the year in decimal format.

```
time(Seatbelts)
```

If we need to change the format, then convert to `yearmon` class (after checking the `frequency` to make sure it is monthly as @Rui Barradas commented)

```
zoo::as.yearmon(time(Seatbelts))
```

-output

```
 [1] "Jan 1969" "Feb 1969" "Mar 1969" "Apr 1969" "May 1969" "Jun 1969" "Jul 1969" "Aug 1969" "Sep 1969" "Oct 1969" "Nov 1969"
 [12] "Dec 1969" "Jan 1970" "Feb 1970" "Mar 1970" "Apr 1970" "May 1970" "Jun 1970" "Jul 1970" "Aug 1970" "Sep 1970" "Oct 1970"
 [23] "Nov 1970" "Dec 1970" "Jan 1971" "Feb 1971" "Mar 1971" "Apr 1971" "May 1971" "Jun 1971" "Jul 1971" "Aug 1971" "Sep 1971"
 [34] "Oct 1971" "Nov 1971" "Dec 1971" "Jan 1972" "Feb 1972" "Mar 1972" "Apr 1972" "May 1972" "Jun 1972" "Jul 1972" "Aug 1972"
 [45] "Sep 1972" "Oct 1972" "Nov 1972" "Dec 1972" "Jan 1973" "Feb 1973" "Mar 1973" "Apr 1973" "May 1973" "Jun 1973" "Jul 1973"
 [56] "Aug 1973" "Sep 1973" "Oct 1973" "Nov 1973" "Dec 1973" "Jan 1974" "Feb 1974" "Mar 1974" "Apr 1974" "May 1974" "Jun 1974"
 [67] "Jul 1974" "Aug 1974" "Sep 1974" "Oct 1974" "Nov 1974" "Dec 1974" "Jan 1975" "Feb 1975" "Mar 1975" "Apr 1975" "May 1975"
 [78] "Jun 1975" "Jul 1975" "Aug 1975" "Sep 1975" "Oct 1975" "Nov 1975" "Dec 1975" "Jan 1976" "Feb 1976" "Mar 1976" "Apr 1976"
 [89] "May 1976" "Jun 1976" "Jul 1976" "Aug 1976" "Sep 1976" "Oct 1976" "Nov 1976" "Dec 1976" "Jan 1977" "Feb 1977" "Mar 1977"
[100] "Apr 1977" "May 1977" "Jun 1977" "Jul 1977" "Aug 1977" "Sep 1977" "Oct 1977" "Nov 1977" "Dec 1977" "Jan 1978" "Feb 1978"
[111] "Mar 1978" "Apr 1978" "May 1978" "Jun 1978" "Jul 1978" "Aug 1978" "Sep 1978" "Oct 1978" "Nov 1978" "Dec 1978" "Jan 1979"
[122] "Feb 1979" "Mar 1979" "Apr 1979" "May 1979" "Jun 1979" "Jul 1979" "Aug 1979" "Sep 1979" "Oct 1979" "Nov 1979" "Dec 1979"
[133] "Jan 1980" "Feb 1980" "Mar 1980" "Apr 1980" "May 1980" "Jun 1980" "Jul 1980" "Aug 1980" "Sep 1980" "Oct 1980" "Nov 1980"
[144] "Dec 1980" "Jan 1981" "Feb 1981" "Mar 1981" "Apr 1981" "May 1981" "Jun 1981" "Jul 1981" "Aug 1981" "Sep 1981" "Oct 1981"
[155] "Nov 1981" "Dec 1981" "Jan 1982" "Feb 1982" "Mar 1982" "Apr 1982" "May 1982" "Jun 1982" "Jul 1982" "Aug 1982" "Sep 1982"
[166] "Oct 1982" "Nov 1982" "Dec 1982" "Jan 1983" "Feb 1983" "Mar 1983" "Apr 1983" "May 1983" "Jun 1983" "Jul 1983" "Aug 1983"
[177] "Sep 1983" "Oct 1983" "Nov 1983" "Dec 1983" "Jan 1984" "Feb 1984" "Mar 1984" "Apr 1984" "May 1984" "Jun 1984" "Jul 1984"
[188] "Aug 1984" "Sep 1984" "Oct 1984" "Nov 1984" "Dec 1984"
```

Or as @G Grothendieck mentioned, converting to `zoo` and then extract the index

```
library(zoo)
index(as.zoo(Seatbelts) )
```

Comment: You could add that by checking `frequency(Seatbelts)` the user can know that the series is monthly data and then call `as.yearmon`.

Comment: Also converting Seatbelts to zoo would create a zoo object with yearmon index. `library(zoo); as.zoo(Seatbelts)`

Comment: Thanks `zoo::as.Date(time(Seatbelts))` feels like best practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the xts function, extract the index and then convert it into a date format:

```
library(xts)
as.Date(index(as.xts(Seatbelts)), format = "%M %Y")
```

Output:

```
  [1] "1969-01-01" "1969-02-01" "1969-03-01" "1969-04-01" "1969-05-01" "1969-06-01" "1969-07-01" "1969-08-01"
  [9] "1969-09-01" "1969-10-01" "1969-11-01" "1969-12-01" "1970-01-01" "1970-02-01" "1970-03-01" "1970-04-01"
 [17] "1970-05-01" "1970-06-01" "1970-07-01" "1970-08-01" "1970-09-01" "1970-10-01" "1970-11-01" "1970-12-01"
 [25] "1971-01-01" "1971-02-01" "1971-03-01" "1971-04-01" "1971-05-01" "1971-06-01" "1971-07-01" "1971-08-01"
 [33] "1971-09-01" "1971-10-01" "1971-11-01" "1971-12-01" "1972-01-01" "1972-02-01" "1972-03-01" "1972-04-01"
 [41] "1972-05-01" "1972-06-01" "1972-07-01" "1972-08-01" "1972-09-01" "1972-10-01" "1972-11-01" "1972-12-01"
 [49] "1973-01-01" "1973-02-01" "1973-03-01" "1973-04-01" "1973-05-01" "1973-06-01" "1973-07-01" "1973-08-01"
 [57] "1973-09-01" "1973-10-01" "1973-11-01" "1973-12-01" "1974-01-01" "1974-02-01" "1974-03-01" "1974-04-01"
 [65] "1974-05-01" "1974-06-01" "1974-07-01" "1974-08-01" "1974-09-01" "1974-10-01" "1974-11-01" "1974-12-01"
 [73] "1975-01-01" "1975-02-01" "1975-03-01" "1975-04-01" "1975-05-01" "1975-06-01" "1975-07-01" "1975-08-01"
 [81] "1975-09-01" "1975-10-01" "1975-11-01" "1975-12-01" "1976-01-01" "1976-02-01" "1976-03-01" "1976-04-01"
 [89] "1976-05-01" "1976-06-01" "1976-07-01" "1976-08-01" "1976-09-01" "1976-10-01" "1976-11-01" "1976-12-01"
 [97] "1977-01-01" "1977-02-01" "1977-03-01" "1977-04-01" "1977-05-01" "1977-06-01" "1977-07-01" "1977-08-01"
[105] "1977-09-01" "1977-10-01" "1977-11-01" "1977-12-01" "1978-01-01" "1978-02-01" "1978-03-01" "1978-04-01"
[113] "1978-05-01" "1978-06-01" "1978-07-01" "1978-08-01" "1978-09-01" "1978-10-01" "1978-11-01" "1978-12-01"
[121] "1979-01-01" "1979-02-01" "1979-03-01" "1979-04-01" "1979-05-01" "1979-06-01" "1979-07-01" "1979-08-01"
[129] "1979-09-01" "1979-10-01" "1979-11-01" "1979-12-01" "1980-01-01" "1980-02-01" "1980-03-01" "1980-04-01"
[137] "1980-05-01" "1980-06-01" "1980-07-01" "1980-08-01" "1980-09-01" "1980-10-01" "1980-11-01" "1980-12-01"
[145] "1981-01-01" "1981-02-01" "1981-03-01" "1981-04-01" "1981-05-01" "1981-06-01" "1981-07-01" "1981-08-01"
[153] "1981-09-01" "1981-10-01" "1981-11-01" "1981-12-01" "1982-01-01" "1982-02-01" "1982-03-01" "1982-04-01"
[161] "1982-05-01" "1982-06-01" "1982-07-01" "1982-08-01" "1982-09-01" "1982-10-01" "1982-11-01" "1982-12-01"
[169] "1983-01-01" "1983-02-01" "1983-03-01" "1983-04-01" "1983-05-01" "1983-06-01" "1983-07-01" "1983-08-01"
[177] "1983-09-01" "1983-10-01" "1983-11-01" "1983-12-01" "1984-01-01" "1984-02-01" "1984-03-01" "1984-04-01"
[185] "1984-05-01" "1984-06-01" "1984-07-01" "1984-08-01" "1984-09-01" "1984-10-01" "1984-11-01" "1984-12-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more option: We could use `.preformat.ts.`. Note this will produce `character` type:

```
my_dates <- rownames(data.frame(.preformat.ts(datasets::Seatbelts), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
my_dates
```

```
[1] "Jan 1969" "Feb 1969" "Mar 1969" "Apr 1969" "May 1969" "Jun 1969" "Jul 1969" "Aug 1969"
  [9] "Sep 1969" "Oct 1969" "Nov 1969" "Dec 1969" "Jan 1970" "Feb 1970" "Mar 1970" "Apr 1970"
 [17] "May 1970" "Jun 1970" "Jul 1970" "Aug 1970" "Sep 1970" "Oct 1970" "Nov 1970" "Dec 1970"
 [25] "Jan 1971" "Feb 1971" "Mar 1971" "Apr 1971" "May 1971" "Jun 1971" "Jul 1971" "Aug 1971"
 [33] "Sep 1971" "Oct 1971" "Nov 1971" "Dec 1971" "Jan 1972" "Feb 1972" "Mar 1972" "Apr 1972"
 [41] "May 1972" "Jun 1972" "Jul 1972" "Aug 1972" "Sep 1972" "Oct 1972" "Nov 1972" "Dec 1972"
 [49] "Jan 1973" "Feb 1973" "Mar 1973" "Apr 1973" "May 1973" "Jun 1973" "Jul 1973" "Aug 1973"
 [57] "Sep 1973" "Oct 1973" "Nov 1973" "Dec 1973" "Jan 1974" "Feb 1974" "Mar 1974" "Apr 1974"
 [65] "May 1974" "Jun 1974" "Jul 1974" "Aug 1974" "Sep 1974" "Oct 1974" "Nov 1974" "Dec 1974"
 [73] "Jan 1975" "Feb 1975" "Mar 1975" "Apr 1975" "May 1975" "Jun 1975" "Jul 1975" "Aug 1975"
 [81] "Sep 1975" "Oct 1975" "Nov 1975" "Dec 1975" "Jan 1976" "Feb 1976" "Mar 1976" "Apr 1976"
 [89] "May 1976" "Jun 1976" "Jul 1976" "Aug 1976" "Sep 1976" "Oct 1976" "Nov 1976" "Dec 1976"
 [97] "Jan 1977" "Feb 1977" "Mar 1977" "Apr 1977" "May 1977" "Jun 1977" "Jul 1977" "Aug 1977"
[105] "Sep 1977" "Oct 1977" "Nov 1977" "Dec 1977" "Jan 1978" "Feb 1978" "Mar 1978" "Apr 1978"
[113] "May 1978" "Jun 1978" "Jul 1978" "Aug 1978" "Sep 1978" "Oct 1978" "Nov 1978" "Dec 1978"
[121] "Jan 1979" "Feb 1979" "Mar 1979" "Apr 1979" "May 1979" "Jun 1979" "Jul 1979" "Aug 1979"
[129] "Sep 1979" "Oct 1979" "Nov 1979" "Dec 1979" "Jan 1980" "Feb 1980" "Mar 1980" "Apr 1980"
[137] "May 1980" "Jun 1980" "Jul 1980" "Aug 1980" "Sep 1980" "Oct 1980" "Nov 1980" "Dec 1980"
[145] "Jan 1981" "Feb 1981" "Mar 1981" "Apr 1981" "May 1981" "Jun 1981" "Jul 1981" "Aug 1981"
[153] "Sep 1981" "Oct 1981" "Nov 1981" "Dec 1981" "Jan 1982" "Feb 1982" "Mar 1982" "Apr 1982"
[161] "May 1982" "Jun 1982" "Jul 1982" "Aug 1982" "Sep 1982" "Oct 1982" "Nov 1982" "Dec 1982"
[169] "Jan 1983" "Feb 1983" "Mar 1983" "Apr 1983" "May 1983" "Jun 1983" "Jul 1983" "Aug 1983"
[177] "Sep 1983" "Oct 1983" "Nov 1983" "Dec 1983" "Jan 1984" "Feb 1984" "Mar 1984" "Apr 1984"
[185] "May 1984" "Jun 1984" "Jul 1984" "Aug 1984" "Sep 1984" "Oct 1984" "Nov 1984" "Dec 1984"
```

Comment: Nice option from `print`

Comment: Or `rownames(.preformat.ts(Seatbelts))` for that matter. Thanks :)